# How to Use Excel DataSource on TestFixture/TestClass C# Selenium Unit Test

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, nunit

I'm an QA intern at the moment at an insurance company and I'm doing some tests on the company's website. I have done many cases and now they're asking for data driven tests which I'm struggling with.

I have done all my tests as;
1 TestFixture
Tests for each page that is in the testcase.

Like this;

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test : BaseClassForTheTest
{
    [Test, Order(1)]
    TestcodeForHomePage

    [Test,Order(2)]
    testcodeForNextPage

}
```

So I need to run the full test, for many datas from excel file. I'm using NUnit as you might have noticed.
The real question is, **how can I pass a DataTable into the TestFixture and make test blocks run for the datatable.** 
On the run, the first test block will run for the first row on the datasheet named `MyTable` and the second test block will run for the first row of the datasheet named `SecondTable`.  Since these tests are triggered by the previous test block, I can't give datasource to the Test blocks.

I've looked up on the internet but couldn't find anything about passing a Datatable into the TestFixture. Thanks in advance people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built into NUnit to read an Excel file. But you can use `TestCaseSource` or `TestFixtureSource` to generate data from anywhere you like.

Your source will have to be a method, which will then read the excel file and return the proper arguments.

Here's an outline using `TestCaseSource`...

```
[TestFixtureSource("DataFromExcel")]
public class MyTestFixture : BaseClassForTheTest
{
    IEnumerable<TestCaseData> DataFromExcel()
    {
        // Read the Excel file
        // For each row of data you want to use
        //     yield return new TestCaseData(/*test fixture args here*/);
    }

    public MyTestFixture(/* your arg list */)
    {
        // Save each arg in a private member
    }

    [Test, Order(1)]
    TestcodeForHomePage()
    {
        // Code that uses the saved values from the constructor
    }

    [Test,Order(2)]
    TestcodeForNextPage()
    {
        // Code that uses the saved values from the constructor
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Charlie!  I've seen this IEnumerable DataFromExcel thingy before but only for Test blocks and had no idea it could be used for TestFixture. I'm truly grateful for the answer.